# Accessing a combobox's SelectedIndex from within a TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq, tablelayoutpanel

I have the following setup:

```
ComboBox cb1 = new ComboBox();
ComboBox cb2 = new ComboBox();
ComboBox cb3 = new ComboBox();
ComboBox cb4 = new ComboBox();
ComboBox cb5 = new ComboBox();

TableLayoutPanel tlpComboBox = new TableLayoutPanel();
tlpComboBox.ColumnCount = 5;
tlpComboBox.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 20F));
tlpComboBox.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 20F));
tlpComboBox.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 20F));
tlpComboBox.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 20F));
tlpComboBox.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 20F));

tlpComboBox.Controls.Add(cb1, 4, 0);
tlpComboBox.Controls.Add(cb2, 3, 0);
tlpComboBox.Controls.Add(cb3, 2, 0);
tlpComboBox.Controls.Add(cb4, 1, 0);
tlpComboBox.Controls.Add(cb5, 0, 0);
```

I'm then trying to check the order of comboBoxes in tlpComboBox. To do this with textboxes, i did the following:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Assert.AreNotEqual(tlpText.Controls[i].Text.ToString(), i.ToString());
}
```

Unfortunately SelectedIndex isnt accessible after Controls[i]. when working with the comboboxes and im a little confused as to why.

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Assert.AreNotEqual(tlpComboBox.Controls[i]. "SelectedIndex isnt accessible", i.ToString());
}
```

Any ideas?

Edit:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBMxh.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast `Controls[i]` to `ComboBox`

```
//sample meta code written in notepad
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Assert.AreNotEqual(
        ((ComboBox )(tlpComboBox.Controls[i])).SelectedIndex , 
        i.ToString());
}
```

This happens because `Controls[i]` is of type (I guess) `Control` which doesn't have the `SelectedIndex` property.

Comment: Do you know why i didnt need to do this with textboxes? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Check in the debugger or through Intelli Sense what is the type of `Controls[i]`

Comment: See edit to original question, ive uploaded a screenshot. It appears to be Control{combobox}?? Your solution of casting it to a combobox does work though so +1 n ans.

Comment: See it's got `System.Windows.Control` and then some stuff in brackets `{...}`. I am not sure why it is showing brackets, probably a clever debugger hint. This probably didn't happen with `TextBox` because you used a property defined in the `Control` class. Try using something unique for the `TextBox` and you will get the same error.